# Dynamically adjust the width of combobox so the entire string can be shown

Tags: c++, c, winapi, combobox

I am using a combobox control to show names stored in a database ( I need to preserve space, that is why I use it instead of a listview, for example ).

My problem is that sometimes text is longer than the combobox so part of it can not be seen.

Is there a way to resize combobox' listbox so it can entirely show text, or at least to enable some kind of horizontal scrolling so the user can scroll to see the entire text?

*Looking through combobox documentation, I haven't found any style that can solve my problem. Trying to add `WS_HSCROLL` as a style in my `CreateWindowEx` call didn't help either.*
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`CB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775907(v=vs.85).aspx) message.

> An application sends the CB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT message to set the width, in pixels, by which a list box can be scrolled horizontally (the scrollable width). **If the width of the list box is smaller than this value, the horizontal scroll bar horizontally scrolls items in the list box. If the width of the list box is equal to or greater than this value, the horizontal scroll bar is hidden** or, if the combo box has the CBS_DISABLENOSCROLL style, disabled.
>
> Parameters
>
> wParam
>   Specifies the scrollable width of the list box, in pixels
>
> lParam
>   This parameter is not used.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but before I officially accept it, please answer me on this follow up: How will i get the width of the text in pixels? I know that it can be done when we draw on device context, but do not know how to do it here. To make things easier, maximum number of the characters in the field is 50 ( I hope this narrows it down ). Best regards, and thank you for a swift and useful answer.

Comment: Use [`GetWindowDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144947.aspx) to get an HDC from the combo box and [`SelectObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957.aspx) the combo box's font into it, then [`GetTextExtentPoint32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938.aspx) to get the pixel width of the longest string in your list.

Comment: I was afraid of that approach... It might be better to do this in handling of `WM_SETFONT` handler or similar... BTW, [`CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) works as well, but overall result is different -> "your way" has scrollbar in listbox while "my way" doesn't. Perhaps your choice is more flexible, so I have officially accepted it.

Comment: `CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH` sets the **minimum width of the listbox itself**. `CB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT` sets the **scrolling width of the listbox content**. They are not mutually exclusive, you can use them together.